# How to deal with Kiwi? Can't run first tests (Installed via Cocoapods)

Tags: ios, unit-testing, configuration, kiwi

I'm trying to run my first Kiwi tests. I use Xcode 5 and Kiwi 2.0 for iOS (installed via Cocoapods). I wrote some tests but when I press 'cmd+u' output in console look like following:

**Log**

```
2013-09-25 19:17:04.347 KiwiPro[36355:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xc1665d0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2013-09-25 17:17:04 +0000
Test Suite 'All tests' finished at 2013-09-25 17:17:04 +0000.
Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.001) seconds
```

**Test:**

```
#import "Kiwi.h"
#import "Person.h"

SPEC_BEGIN(MySpec)

describe(@"When Person born", ^{
    Person *person = [Person new];
    it(@"Should be age of 0", ^{
    [[theValue([person age]) should] equal:theValue(0)];
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

And here is **Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

target :KiwiProTests, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'Kiwi', '~> 2.0'
end
```

I think that tests aren't compiled. In linke below my project with Kiwi and test are available.

**Project on dropbox**

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11493275/Tmp/KiwiPro.zip

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this? Same problem for me

Comment: Nope :/ Still waiting for help.

Comment: Actually I solved it now. I will add the solution as an answer

Answer (score 10):

This also happened to me today. When using `Xcode 5`, you have to setup the unit test target as `OCUnit`, or you can easily change the pod in `Kiwi/XCTest`

Comment: I pulled in Kiwi/XCTest using the Podfile and it works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In case Viks answer does not help you (as it did not for me):

**My scenario**

When I first created the project (under XCode 5), I let XCode create a test target for me. When I tried to switch to Kiwi then (following the guide on [Getting-Started-with-Kiwi-2.0](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Kiwi-2.0)) I stumbled across the same error: no tests were run.

**My solution**

It turned out that removing the whole test target (I also removed all the related files in the targets folder) and recreating it from scratch fixed it!

Comment: I just had to remove the target in the scheme and readd to make it work, but this answer basically did it for me.